# Recursively Linking Records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say we have a table that consists of 10 jobs. Sometimes jobs can reference other jobs. For example, let's say each job is either a complete shuttle route, or part of a shuttle route. If it's a complete shuttle route, then the fields [prev] and [next] will both be null. If it's just one leg of a route, then at least one of those fields will have a reference to another job, namely, the job which came before or after it in the route sequence.

Here's what the table looks like.

[image]

I'd like to be able to query the table for all jobs where either 1) [grab_me] is true, or 2) it's part of a route where any legs (jobs) [grab_me] field is set to true. So basically, "Grab these jobs, and anything they're attached to."

In this case, the desired result is as follows:

[image]

I've been able to get it working by taking the union of two recursive CTEs, but my understanding of SQL isn't anywhere near what I wish it was and I feel like there's a simpler way.

Here's my current setup:

```
declare @t table (job int, prev int, next int, grab_me bit)
insert  @t (job, prev, next, grab_me)
values  (1, null, null, 0),
        (2, null, 3, 0),
        (3, 2, 4, 0),
        (4, 3, null, 0),
        (5, null, null, 1),
        (6, null, null, 1),
        (7, null, 8, 0),
        (8, 7, 9, 1),
        (9, 8, 10, 0),
        (10, 9, null, 0)

select * from @t;

with cte_1 as (
    select  job, prev, next, grab_me
    from    @t
    where   grab_me = 1

    union all

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me
    from    @t child
    join    cte_1 parent
    on      parent.prev = child.job
),
cte_2 as (
    select  job, prev, next, grab_me
    from    @t
    where   grab_me = 1

    union all

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me
    from    @t child
    join    cte_2 parent
    on      parent.next = child.job
)

select * from cte_1 union select * from cte_2;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query? It's returning your expected result.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I feel like I should be able to pull it off with a single rcte. The problem is, though, when I join on (parent.prev = child.job or parent.next = child.job) it explodes with a max recursion limit error. If it's not possible with a single rcte, I'm curious as to why.

Comment: @BrentBarbata, I have a feeling that it would be possible, if it was a `tree`, not a double-linked list, as it is now. When you try to traverse the list in both directions simultaneously `(parent.prev = child.job or parent.next = child.job)` you end up looping infinitely between two adjacent elements. When you have two explicit CTEs; with first CTE you always go to the "left" node; with second CTE you always go to the "right" node. Thus the nodes never repeat as you traverse them. If it was possible to somehow mark nodes that you've visited, then you could go in both directions at once.

Comment: @wewesthemenace, it turns out it is possible to do it with a single CTE, which should be more efficient than original approach. Have a look at execution plans in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a variant that technically uses one CTE. I had to explicitly indicate which direction the recursion should traverse to avoid infinite loop. I didn't know before this question that it is possible to have [multiple recursive members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175972.aspx) in one CTE.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    select  job, prev, next, grab_me, 1 AS UsePrev, 1 AS UseNext
    from    @t
    where   grab_me = 1

    UNION ALL

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me, 1 AS UsePrev, 0 AS UseNext
    from    
        @t child 
        inner join cte parent on 
            parent.prev = child.job
            AND parent.UsePrev = 1

    UNION ALL

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me, 0 AS UsePrev, 1 AS UseNext
    from    
        @t child 
        inner join cte parent on 
            parent.next = child.job
            AND parent.UseNext = 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Result set:

```
job    prev    next    grab_me    UsePrev    UseNext
5      NULL    NULL    1          1          1
6      NULL    NULL    1          1          1
8      7       9       1          1          1
7      NULL    8       0          1          0
9      8       10      0          0          1
10     9       NULL    0          0          1
```

The execution plan is significantly different to the first variant. The execution plan of the whole batch that consists of populating the table variable, original query and new query had 22% for INSERT, 55% for original query, 23% for the new query. It is too big to fit into screen.

So, the new variant may be more efficient, but it has to be checked with the real data.

**single CTE, second version**

It turns out we can do it without two recursive members after all:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    select  job, prev, next, grab_me, 1 AS UsePrev, 1 AS UseNext
    from    @t
    where   grab_me = 1

    UNION ALL

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me
        , CASE WHEN parent.prev = child.job AND parent.UsePrev = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UsePrev
        , CASE WHEN parent.next = child.job AND parent.UseNext = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UseNext
    from
        @t AS child 
        inner join cte AS parent on
            (parent.prev = child.job AND parent.UsePrev = 1)
            OR
            (parent.next = child.job AND parent.UseNext = 1)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Execution plan for the last version is again simpler and estimated to be even more efficient.

If batch includes initialization, original query, my first variant and my second variant the query costs are: insert 19%, original 48%, my first version 20%, my second version 13%.

**insert**

[image: insert]

**original query**

[image: original query]

**first variant**

[image: first variant]

**second variant**

[image: second variant]

### **Final variant**

In the second variant we can remove extra columns `UsePrev`, `UseNext` and use existing columns `prev` and `next` for this purpose. The logic is still the same. If the go from the parent to the child using parent's `prev` link, then set this child's `next` link (that points to this parent) to `NULL`, so that we don't traverse back to the same parent again. Similarly, if we go from the parent to the child using parent's `next` link, then set this child's `prev` link to `NULL`.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    select  job, prev, next, grab_me
    from    @t
    where   grab_me = 1

    UNION ALL

    select  child.job
        , CASE WHEN parent.next = child.job THEN NULL ELSE child.prev END AS prev
        , CASE WHEN parent.prev = child.job THEN NULL ELSE child.next END AS next
        , child.grab_me
    from
        @t AS child 
        inner join cte AS parent on
            (parent.prev = child.job)
            OR
            (parent.next = child.job)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Execution plan is very similar to the second variant, just one `Compute Scalar` less:

[image: third and final variant]

BTW, execution plan of the query suggested by @cha in another answer is exactly the same as execution plan of my first variant.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for putting so much thought into my question. This is a GREAT answer and so helpful to me.

Comment: @BrentBarbata, you are welcome. It is a pleasure to answer an interesting and well-asked question.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a single cte if you introduce a `level` column. The level is 0 for the parent node, and is either positive or negative number depending on which way you go. Using this pseudo-column you can make your recursive query work:

```
with cte_1 as (
    select  job, prev, next, grab_me, 0 as level
    from    @t
    where   grab_me = 1

    union all

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me, parent.level + 1
    from    @t child
    join    cte_1 parent
    on      parent.prev = child.job and parent.level >= 0

    union all

    select  child.job, child.prev, child.next, child.grab_me, parent.level - 1
    from    @t child
    join    cte_1 parent
    on      parent.next = child.job and parent.level <= 0
)
select * from cte_1 ;

result
job         prev        next        grab_me level
----------- ----------- ----------- ------- -----------
5           NULL        NULL        1       0
6           NULL        NULL        1       0
8           7           9           1       0
7           NULL        8           0       1
9           8           10          0       -1
10          9           NULL        0       -2

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Introducing the `level` column is a great way to illustrate exactly why my original thought of `parent.prev = child.job or parent.next = child.job` doesn't work.